# What is the solution of the ODE for the quadratically damped harmonically driven oscillator, e.g. the linearized pendulum in air.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There are many sources for the driven linear damped and even many for the quadratically and constant damped regimes of free (not driven) ODE solutions, but more useful is the quadratically damped and driven ODE solution.  This is theoretical as electro-magnetically clock pendula are pulse driven. (mechanically driven pendulua are also pulsed. I've not found this after much searching.  Of interest, as one may find the Q from band width of the linear damped driven (harmonically) oscillator, but I suspect that formula is invalid with other damping regimes. Obviously must be, as the Q is not constant, but is dependent on the amplitude.  The bandwidth method for the linear dissipation oscillator is independent of the amplitude.

bc maths declined

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Did you read your title and your post? How are we supposed to make sense of it? Can you clean it up and share what you have tried? Regards

Comment: Yes, I've done it.  I had edited, but the originally is what the app. posted.

Comment: You want to solve something like this ?             $$m\ddot x+\lambda \dot{x}^2 + kx=A*\sin(t)$$

Comment: Yes!  This is the std. ODE for a spring oscillator wherein sqrt(k/m) = the undamped (natural) radian frequency, and x dot squared is the drag (quadratic dissipation) force, but, of course, you know that.  It's easily modified for a linearized pendulum.  I don't need the complication of the more accurate theta + e*theta cubed for the pendulum's restoring force.